# How to compile C program without using limits.h header file in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I made a calculator in C and now, I want to compile my program without using limits.h header file in GCC. But I don't know how.

Here is my program source code:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
int scanf(const char *format, ...);

int main()
{
    double num1, num2, r;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        scanf("%lf", &num1);
        scanf("%lf", &num2);
        printf("\ta - Add\n\tb - Substract\n\tc - Multiply\n\td - Divide\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'a':
                r = num1 + num2;
                printf("%lf + %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                break;
            case 'b':
                r = num1 - num2;
                printf("%lf - %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                break;
            case 'c':
                r = num1 * num2;
                printf("%lf * %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                break;
            case 'd':
                r = num1 / num2;
                if (num1 > 0 & num2 == 0 | num1 == 0 & num2 == 0)
                {
                    printf("Undefined\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%lf / %lf = %f\n", num1, num2, r);
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid\n");
        }
    }
    while (1);
}
```

I compiled my program with `gcc Program.c -o ConsoleCalculator1`.

Comment: I suppose _not_ including the header file isn't good enough for you. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can exclude it as long as you don't use any of the values in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifndef TEST
#include<limits.h>
#endif
```

Then, during compilation use `-D` tag as :

```
gcc -DTEST -Wall file-name.c -o file-exec
```

Using `-D`, defines macro TEST, hence it will not include `limits.h`

If you want to include `limits.h`, then donot define macro TEST (donot use `-D` compiler option)